# Where to buy replacement thermostat jumper U-shape wire

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have lost the U-shaped jumper wire used for my old thermostat installation. Now, I am trying to reinstall the old thermostat but I am missing the jumper. Although I could use some spare wire or other solutions, I'd like to reinstall with the U-shaped jumper wire.

Here's that jumper:

[image]

Does it need to be thermostat-grade wire (i.e., low-voltage, etc.)? Where would I find this solid wire?

Comment: any solid 18 gauge wire will do

Comment: Pretty much any wire will do.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like zinc plated wire, perhaps from a paperclip, but really there is no reason not to to use some of your spare wire.

Comment: Where are you seeing "zinc plated wire" here?  All the wires in the photo appear to be stranded copper wire.

Comment: That link between  `Rc` and `R` has a zinc colour same as the mounting screw.

Comment: Ok, I see it now.  Thanks!